# SQL Server return wrong result with LIKE statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a tablet with these data

**Sample data**

[image]

When I try

```
SELECT *
FROM [PipiShop].[dbo].[ProductCategories]
where Name like '%n%' escape '/'
```

Result went wrong with 2 results

```
(extractly: Điện lạnh, Viễn thông, Đồ gia dụng; because it's contains 'n' charater)
```

I also tried on my PC and result is true

I don't know what problem with my laptop ><

Thank you

**Wrong result**

[image]

Comment: What am I missing - both results have an `n` in them as far as I can see?!

Comment: Both results have '%n%' so its returning.. What you are expecting?

Comment: Is it that you expect `Đồ gia dụng` to *also* be in the results?

Comment: @Jamiec That's what I assume is wrong, it's not showing that row

Comment: Edit, I found problem with table's collation. Default is Vietnamese_CI_AS, I changed to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, so it run true. Sorry for my bad English